# Explanation of Specific Chemical Shifts on an H-NMR Spectrum

Tags: analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

Recently, I've been looking into chemical shifts on H-NMR Spectrums and I came across a graph I didn't quite understand...

As you can see from the spectrum attached, the signal emitted from the protons near the Cl (colour coded orange) is further downfield than the signal emitted by the protons near the O (colour coded dark blue). However, shouldn't the protons near the Oxygen be further downfield due to their proximity towards the more electronegative atom? How can this be explained?

[image]

Comment: Actually, more interesting question is how $3^\circ \  \ce{-OCH}$ is more shielded than  $1^\circ \  \ce{-OCH3}$.